# Dealing with failed futures

Tags: playframework, future, playframework-2.3

In Play Framework 2.3, an action can produce a result from a successful future call like this:

```scala
def index = Action.async {
  val futureInt = scala.concurrent.Future { intensiveComputation() }
  futureInt.map(i => Ok("Got result: " + i))
}
```

But how can an action deal with a failed future call, i.e., a future that was completed by calling `failure()` instead of `success()`?

For instance, how could an action produce a `InternalServerError` result with the message returned in the future's failure's throwable?

`onComplete` and `onFailure` callbacks don't seem to fit the action's flow (it needs to return a result, either from a successful future or a failed one).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a single `Action`, you can do this with `recover`, recovering the failed `Future` to a `Result`:

```
def index = Action.async {
    val futureInt = scala.concurrent.Future { intensiveComputation() }
    futureInt.map(i => Ok("Got result: " + i))
        .recover{ case e: Exception => InternalServerError(e.getMessage) }
}
```

`recover` in this case is a `PartialFunction[Throwable, Result]`, so you can be more fine grained with your error handling, and anything that is not defined in the `PartialFunction` will remain a failed `Future`. More generally, you could probably use a custom defined `Action` that implements this.